# column names and types for insert operation in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am building a sqlite browser in Python/sqlalchemy.

Here is my requirement.
I want to do insert operation on the table.
I need to pass a table name to a function. It should return all columns along with the respective types.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in sqlalchemy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all columns of a `Table` like this:

```
my_table.c
```

Which returns a type that behaves similar to a dictionary, i.e. it has `values` method and so on:

```
columns = [(item.name, item.type) for item in my_table.c.values()]
```

You can play around with that to see what you can get from that. Using the declarative extension you can access the table through the class' `__table__` attribute. Furthermore, you might find the [Runtime Inspection API](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/inspection.html) helpful.